# SDWebImage error downloaded image has 0 pixels

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiimageview, sdwebimage

Using SDWebImage latest swift library version getting following error while loading few urls

**Downloaded image has 0 pixels**

Following is code

```
if let url = URL(string: storeImgStr.encoded), !(storeImgStr.isEmpty) {
        self.storeImg.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: Constants.storeImagePlaceorderImage)) {
            (image, error, cahce, url) in
            if(error != nil) {
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        self.storeImg.image = UIImage(named: Constants.storeImagePlaceorderImage)

    }
```

my url looks something like this **cant share exact url due to policy issues domain name is changed**

https://tximages.mydomain.in/retailers_data_v2/retailer/320/3306-1-Aviator.jpg

Following is error code

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "(null)"
```

**Also I am able to open image url in web browser.**

What exactly is the issue here?

Following extension used to encode url

```
extension String {
var encoded: String {
    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
}
}
```

**Update:** Able to open above image URL in the Chrome browser but not able to open it in the Safari browser any reason for that?

Comment: Could you please show the `encoded` method of your extension to `String`?
I tested your code with test image, [seems good](https://pastebin.com/DC7bkdBH)

Comment: updated question please check

Comment: `encoded` is fine. Tested with this link `https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit Blogging.com Now` - perfectly encodes it into `https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit%20Blogging.com%20Now`. The issue is with your the image link.

Comment: but 90% urls are working fine in app only few urls not working

Comment: also same url is working fine in android app and web browser

Comment: What I would recommend, is to 1) list those links 2) check if they could be opened in iOS Safari 3) create a WKWebView and test the (failed) link if it is available at all for opening. [For instance try this](https://pastebin.com/sVDbr35J)

Comment: Hey @amodkanthe Did you make it work?

Comment: no not yet some url are not opening in safari only but working on chrome and android app i dont know why

Comment: What did you do then?

Comment: Nothing as there are few images done nothing and asked web team to check no solution yet

Answer (score 3):

`-1100` means `NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`. Also there is a possibility, that the server does not return a file [to specific country](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/986#issuecomment-93899157) or due to [specific symbols](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/1126) in the `urlString`. In this case you could apply the following encoding: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`.
You could also use [SDWebImageRetryFailed](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/319322fbd55d2d6d3fc4076f5250997be5872c19/Docs/SDWebImage-5.0-Migration-guide.md#error-codes-and-domain) as it described in the [documentation](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/3f29a3ef1e5b980f1f31949f22938525bd5dfe12/SDWebImage/MapKit/MKAnnotationView%2BWebCache.h#L118), more about [this flag](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/96bb7b753e0759368846c9a987fd72cee7d0db7d/SDWebImage/Core/SDWebImageDefine.h#L57):

```
storeImg.sd_setImage(with: urlEncoded, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: Constants.storeImagePlaceorderImage), options: .retryFailed) { // handle result completion }
```

You could test your broken link with the following:

```swift
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
import WebKit

extension String {
    var encoded: String {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let testURL = "https://i.groupme.com/638x640.jpeg.d4f31c747b534baca03d12db5a2b6193"
    let testURLShouldEncode = "https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Visit Blogging.com Now"

    var storeImg: UIImageView!
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureUI()

        if let urlEncoded = URL(string: testURLShouldEncode.encoded), !(testURL.isEmpty) {
            storeImg.sd_setImage(with: urlEncoded, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: Constants.storeImagePlaceorderImage)) { 
                [unowned self] (image, error, cahce, url) in
                print("image \(String(describing: image))")
                print("error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                print("cache \(cahce)")
                print("url \(String(describing: url))")
                if (error != nil) {
                    let request = URLRequest(url: urlEncoded)
                    self.webView.load(request)
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.storeImg.image = UIImage(named: Constants.storeImagePlaceorderImage)
        }
    }

    func configureUI() {
        storeImg = UIImageView()
        storeImg.contentMode = .center
        storeImg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(storeImg)
        view.addSubview(webView)

        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        storeImg.backgroundColor = .yellow
        webView.backgroundColor = .orange

        storeImg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        storeImg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        storeImg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        storeImg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeImg.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the problem too, and my solution was done by ADDING `"SD_WEBP=1"` into your `SDWebImage` target -> `Build Settings` -> `Preprocessor Macros`.
[image]